# Prove that $8p^2+2p+1$ is prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

If $p$ and $8p^2+1$ is prime number than $$8p^2+2p+1$$ is prime number proof.

I know that prime number can write as a multiply 1 and $8p^2+2p+1$, so if I show that this number is a multiply $a*b$ where $a\not=1$ and $b\not=1$ than that is not a prime number, can someone help me?

Comment: Where did this come from? A priori, I doubt that this is true.

Comment: When you say you have no idea, I don't believe you. You know things about prime numbers. You must have checked a few obvious general things and a few small primes before you came in here and have us this problem. Please tell us about that!

Comment: (Repeating the definition of prime is not what I referred to. What happens for $p=2$? What about $3,5$ or $7$? Does it help to look at it modulo $4$ or $6$? These are things you should _always try_ in any problem about primes unless a solution comes to you immediately.)

Comment: Questions like this appear in many slight variations - all solvable by exactly the same idea. I chose one as a dupe, but there are *many* others, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628115/for-which-primes-p-is-p2-2-also-prime) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/565066/242) and [here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/269790/242)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p = 3k\pm 1$ then $8p^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod3$ so $8p^2+1=3$ which is imposibile. So $p=3$ then $8p^2+2p+1 = 79$