# Prove that $n$ and $n^2+2$ are prime if and only if $n = 3 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Here is where I started

Note that $n$ must be a prime number
Note that $n = 2$ is not a solution
Note that $n = 3$ is a solution
Assume there is some prime number $p$ such that $p > 3$ and $p$ and $p^2 + 2$ are prime

$p$ can be written as $3+k$ where $k$ is an even natural number

hence,$$ p^2+2 = (3+k)^2+2 = 9+6k+k^2+2$$
$$= k^2 + 6k + 11$$
I am stuck, I don't know where to go even though I know k is even...

Comment: Hint: any integer can be written in the form $3k$ or $3k+1$ or $3k+2$. Check what happens in each case.

Comment: Hint: You can also write $k$ as $2m+1$, being m an integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [For which primes p is $p^2 + 2$ also prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/628115/for-which-primes-p-is-p2-2-also-prime) - found through using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24p%5E2%2B2%24%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24p%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Aprime&p=1). Note there are also other duplicates, e.g., [Suppose that both $p$ and $p^2 +2$ are prime numbers. Show that $p=3$.](/q/1218152), and also very similar ones where it asks to show $p^3+2$ is also prime, e.g., [Squares, Cubes and Prime numbers](/q/872769).

Answer (score 6):

Now I see,
$p =3k+1, 3k-1$

$p≡ \pm1 \mod 3$

$p^2≡ 1 \mod 3$

$p^2+2 ≡ 0 \mod 3$

$p^2+2$ is always divisible by 3, hence it cannot be prime

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: What does Dupe mean

Comment: Abbreviation of duplicate.

Comment: Should I delete the question then

Comment: That would be best, since we already have way too many questions like this (thee more dupes the harder it is for users to locate the "best" answers).